# c# how to clear textboxes of user control from main form

Tags: c#

I have one form which contain the my user control. How to clear all then textbox of that user control using a button in my main form?## Heading ##

Comment: Winforms, ASP.NET, wpf, ...? You could provide a public method `ClearTextBoxes` in your user-control which you can call from the mainform. Then the logic is encapsulated there, f.e. like: `this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(t => t.Clear())`

Comment: thanks for the idea.. 

foreach (Control x in panel3.Controls)
{
                    if (x is supplierUI)
                    {
                        ((supplierUI)x).Clear();
                    }
}

this code works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to clear all TextBoxes, just call it from your main form:

```
public void ClearTextBoxes(bool searchRecursively = true)
{
    Action<Control.ControlCollection, bool> clearTextBoxes = null;
    clearTextBoxes = (controls, searchChildren) =>
    {
        foreach (Control c in controls)
        {
            TextBox txt = c as TextBox;
            txt?.Clear();
            if (searchChildren && c.HasChildren)
                clearTextBoxes(c.Controls, true);
        }
    };

    clearTextBoxes(this.Controls, searchRecursively);
}
```